# Ошибка сегментации при обращению к динамичному массиву

Tags: c++, массивы, ссылки

Здравствуйте! Вроде бы вопрос простой, но причину бага я найти не смог:

```
class World{
    public:
        ...
        Block ***getTerrain(){ return &this->terrain; }; 
        ...
    private:
        Block **terrain;
}
```

Есть класс, у которого есть массив объектов. При обращении в массиву внутри класса (типа `this->terrain[i][j].getType()`), все нормально, но когда я пытаюсь использовать возращенную функцией `getTerrain` ссылку (`this->world->getTerrain()[i][j]->getType()`), происходит ошибка сегментации. В чем проблема?

Да, кстати, когда я обращаюсь к нулевым элементам (`this->world->getTerrain()[0][0]->getType()`), все проходит нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код делает не одно и то же.

В первом случае вы обращаетесь к объекту

```
terrain[i][j]
```

во втором — к

```
*((&terrain)[i][j])
```

Первое от адреса, на который указывает `terrain`, отходит на `i * sizeof(Block*)`, находит указатель там, и смещается от него на `j * sizeof(Block)`.

Второе от адреса, на который указывает `terrain`, отходит на `i * sizeof(Block**)`, находит указатель там, и смещается от него на `j * sizeof(Block*)`.

Скорее всего, `sizeof(Block**)` и `sizeof(Block*)` равны (т. к. указатель на данные), но `sizeof(Block*)` и `sizeof(Block)` нет.

Попробуйте так:

```
Block** terrain = *(this->world->getTerrain());
terrain[i][j].getType();
```

Ну или вы можете переделать функцию `getTerrain`, чтобы она не возвращала не тройной, а двойной указатель.

Comment: Как в таком случае нужно обращаться к массиву?

Comment: @reload: Дописал ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Но в таком случае изменения в массиве не будут видны из класса, верно?

Comment: @reload: Нет, почему же? Только если вы захотите поменять само поле `terrain`, это не будет видно, т. к. вы получаете копию `terrain`. А значения, на которые указывает `terrain`, один и те же в обеих случаях. Попробуйте!

Comment: Хм... сработало! Никогда бы не подумал... Спасибо!

Comment: @reload: Пожалуйста!